# Handling fonts in Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

i was thinking if Microsoft made one OS for Tablets and PC's - Windows 8. Then there just must be a way to control FontSize. Example i have a Main grid with 4 columns:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="First Title"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Second Longer In Characters Title" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

On a small device it looks like this:

[image]

On bigger device like this:

[image]

It's not readable!

I have tried the ViewBox solution, **BUT**

The same FontSizes now have different size, because of the characters count

Example:

[image]

Then i have tried to put all the page in a ViewBox:

[image]

It also isn't good because it ruins all my star sized grids.

So the questions are:

1) Is there a way to calculate TextBlock width when i change the FontSize?
So i could do something like:

```
foreach (TextBlock on a page)
{
  //Find the textblock with biggest amount of characters
}
do
{
     FoundTextBlock.FontSize=FontSize+1;
}
while (FoundTextBlock.WidthInPixel fits 200px)
foreach (TextBlock on a page)
{
  //Set all text blocks the same FontSize
}
```

2) Is there a way of getting ViewBoxes current stretching koeficient, so i could find with the least and apply to others?

3) What does FontStretch= property do? - i cant see the difference?

4) Any other way to handle font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two conclusions ("On a small device it looks like this:", "On bigger device like this:") are wrong. The text sizes only look different to you because your emulator is scaled. (See how both screenshot have the same width)

The texts will be the same size (if measured in inches) on real world devices.

If you want to have the same screen size (measured in percent of screen area), then you might want to wrap the entire page in one Viewbox.